# Image validation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am performing some validations but the validation on image is not working.Although i have applied correct rules but still code is giving me errors as shown below:
**Validation errors**
The image must be a file of type: jpg, png, gif.
The image must be an image.
**Controller**

```
public function register(Request $req){
        $this->validate($req,[
          'Image'          =>   'mimes:jpg,png,gif|image'
         ]);

    }
```

Comment: Is there an `<input type="file">` with a `name="Image"` - capitalization matters - in your form? Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on it?

Comment: yes. input type file and name correct. but no use of enctype.

Comment: Well, you need the enctype.

Comment: Thank You. Solved.